# SQL whole table update with selection from another table based on the first table field

Tags: sql, mysql

table1: name | rating | stat1 | stat2
table2: name | stat3
it is forum and site integration, so they are not normalized

I need to recount rating for users in `table1`.
`rating = stat1 + stat2 + stat3`.
`stat3` is in the `table2`, which has common `name` field with `table1`.

```
UPDATE table1 SET rating = stat1 + stat2 + 
(SELECT stat3 FROM table2 WHERE name = [name_from_table1] )
```

How can I insert `name` from `table1` to use it in the `table2` selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.name=table2.name SET table1.rating=table1.stat1+table1.stat2+table2.stat3
```

Comment: Yep, it is faster, then with select